# alter facet_grid output in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the current version of my figure:

```
    require(MuMIn)
    require(ggplot2)
    data(Cement)
    d <- data.frame(Cement)
    dd <- melt(d,id.var = "y")

ggplot(dd,aes(x = y,y = value, group = variable)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2)  + 
  theme_classic() +
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales = "free") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  guides(colour = FALSE)
```

[image]

How can I

1) Alter this graph so that the X1, X2, X3, and X4 labels are on the left hand side and they read c("factor x^2","factor x^3","factor x^4","factor x^5"),

2) Is there a method for surrounding each panel with a box, to make them more distinguishable?

Comment: are you sure you mean to use `facet_grid` over `facet_wrap` ? You're best off creating another column with the "clean" name you want to use and use that to facet. Panels are clearly distinguishable under the default theme, do you need `theme_classic()`?

Comment: @JPC if she uses facet_grid, she can use https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/labeller; 1) change the factor labels (like `c(expression(x^2), etc))`) in your data set and use `labeller = label_parsed` in `facet_grid`; 2) that is taken away by your theme choice. you can either add it back in or use another; `theme_bw()` might look good. Also, I don't know if it is possible to switch the axes; hadley is very anti-double axes and I've never seen a ggplot with labels on the right side

Comment: @rawr, very nice! did not know about `labeller`, this is fantastic

Comment: OK, so I guess the main solution to 2 was to not use theme_classic but theme_bw instead

Comment: @Kate I haven't seen a solution for the facet labels on the left hand side, for the other questions: see my answer.

Comment: @Kate you can use theme classic, you'd just have to add some elements to make the outer box. theme_bw is just quicker (and built-in)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl))+
  facet_grid(gear~., labeller=label_both) + geom_point() +
  theme(strip.text.y=element_text(angle=90)) + labs(y="")


g <- ggplotGrob(p)

g$layout[g$layout$name == "strip-right",c("l", "r")] <- 2
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Comment: This is great! How would I modify this so that the facet is bigger?

Answer (score 3):

A solution for question 1 (partial) and 2:

```
names(d) <- c("x^1","x^2","x^3","x^4","y")
dd <- melt(d,id.var = "y", variable.name="factor")

ggplot(dd, aes(x = y, y = value, group = factor)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2)  + 
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(factor ~ ., scales = "free", labeller = label_both) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1), panel.grid = element_blank()) + 
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  guides(colour = FALSE)
```

which gives:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. For the factor x^2 this is suppose to be squared, cubed etc. I think this is covered by rawr above.

Answer (score 1):

Using `labeller` is a good option (problem #1) and `facet_grid` and `facet_wrap` have a `switch` argument for moving facet labels around a bit (problem #2):

```
library("ggplot2")
x <- runif(100)
exp <- rep(1:4, each = 25)
y <- x^exp
df <- data.frame(x, y, exp)

# facet_grid
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
facet_grid(exp ~ ., labeller = label_bquote(factor~x^.(exp)), switch = "y") + 
geom_point() + labs(y="") +
theme(strip.background = element_blank()) # Remove facet border if you want

# facet_wrap
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
facet_wrap(~ exp, ncol = 1, labeller = label_bquote(factor~x^.(exp)), switch = "y") + 
geom_point() + labs(y="") +
theme(strip.background = element_blank())
```